# Why does Kiri hate for Norm to be her father?

Tags: avatar-the-way-of-water

In *Avatar The Way of Water* (2022), Spider and Lo’ak are making fun of Kiri because she is the child of Dr. Grace,
who became pregnant with her after becoming intimate with Norm:

> Lo'ak: No, no, no. Think about it, right? I mean, he's the teacher's
> pet. He's out at the lab with her all the time.
>
> Kiri: **I would kill myself. I would drink acid.**

Why does Kiri hate for Norm to be her father?

Comment: If the other guy was her father she'd have been in the trailer and got paid more.